# Hadoop - Most efficient way to get data

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a lot of data in hadoop, which I need to copy into a msql db.

Would it be more efficient to select the columns I need (which is almost all columns) in hive and write the results using `INSERT OVERWRITE` or would it be better to use the `copyToLocal` shell command to copy the file and manually transform the data?

Answer (score 2):

if your data is in hadoop , you can just use the Sqoop to move it MYSQL DB. Directly using SQOOP will be efficient then adding another extra layer of HIVE. Get the MYSQL connector and You can try some thing like below , let me know more help needed .

bin/sqoop export  --connect jdbc:mysql:/// --table   -username  -P --export-dir  -m1